# Parse JSON file in linux using jq

Tags: json, linux, file, unix, jq

I have a json file, call it x.json satisfying this schema:

```
 }
      },
      "type": "persons"
    },
    "person's in a group": {
      "primary": {
        "attributes": {
          "firstname": "sara",
          "lastname": "jones",
          "age": "32",
          "weight": "130",
```

to get the list of first name, I have to write:

```
cat x.json | jq '.title[].type[].properties.firstname'
```

is there a shorter way to get the first name? Instead of having to write the whole line of objects? 
Also is there a way to list more than just the first name, for example first and last name? 
lastly, any idea how I can import this out into a CVS file or any other flat file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited your question in several ways. You provided a schema, not an example. also I think you mean the command `jq`, not `jd`.

Also I assume you have to parse a file containing a list of such persons, not just a single person.

With jq, you can run this

```
echo '
[{
  "firstName": "sin",
  "lastName": "minim sint labore"
},
{
  "firstName": "mun",
  "lastName": "minim sint labore"
}]' >> x.json

cat x.json | jq '.[].firstName'
"sin"
"mun"
```

jq has more options that you can find in [their documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), such as:

```
$ jq -c '.[] | [.firstName, .lastName]' x.json
["sin","minim sint labore"]
["mun","minim sint labore"]
```

For transforming such or other JSON output to CSV, look at the documentation, or use google or Stackoverflow.

Comment: I believe that taken literally, the given schema would normally be interpreted as matching a single JSON object, not a JSON array of objects.  See in particular https://cswr.github.io/JsonSchema/spec/arrays/

Comment: That's quite possible, not sure what to do with the OPs schema. The question text refers to "list of first names", so I assumed the OP schema was only describing elements of a list.

Comment: you are correct about the array of objects, so I have actually adjusted my example to match my code.